# Exception when multiple Thread Send messages to single ActiveMQ topic

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

We have been using ActiveMQ to communicate between two services.

(Both services are spring boot services)
**Service B** puts message to some topic - ***example-topic-1*** and **Service A** receives message from that topic and do the process.

Below are the code that I'm using in **Service B**.

**build.gradle**

```
//activeMQ
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq:3.1.0'
```

**application.yml**

```
  broker-url: tcp://localhost:61616
  topic: example-topic-1
```

**ActiveMQConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class ActiveMQConfiguration {

    @Value("${activeMQ.broker-url}")
    private String brokerUrl;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory  = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        return  activeMQConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ActiveMQMessageConverter mActiveMQMessageConverter){
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
        jmsTemplate.setMessageConverter(mActiveMQMessageConverter);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }}
```

**ActiveMQProducerService.java**

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ActiveMQProducerService {

    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Value("${com.activeMQ.topic}")
    private String topic;

    public IngestData sendMessage(IngestData ingestData){
        try{

            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(topic, ingestData);
           
        } catch(Exception e){
            log.error("Received Exception during sending for Message: "+ingestData.toString(), e);
        }
        return ingestData;
    }
}
```

**MainController.java**

```
    @PostMapping("/data/ingest")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)\\
    public void dataIngestJsonHandler(@Valid @RequestBody List<IngestData> listOfIngestData) {

        Map<String , ScadaDataSpec> mapOfScadaDataSpec = new HashMap<>();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        int batchSize=1000;
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfIngestData.size(); i += batchSize) {
            List<IngestData> batch = listOfIngestData.subList(i, Math.min(i + batchSize, listOfIngestData.size()));
            executorService.submit(() -> sendToActiveMQ(batch));
        }
    }
    
    public void sendToActiveMQ(List<IngestData> batch){
        
        batch.forEach(ingestData ->{
            mPiActiveMQProducerService.sendMessage(ingestData);
        });
        
    }
```

Now as per above code in MainController size of listOfIngestData will be aroun 10,000.
So we are using batching to iterate it over 1000 and then process each batch with ExecutorService with threadpool size of 10.

So as per logic each Thread try to insert 1000 messages to ActiveMQ topic. At a same time multiple thread is running and all those thread will try to send messages to ActiveMQ topic.

After some time we get below JSM error.

```
    org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:661) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at com.xxx.yyy.scada.pi.service.ActiveMQProducerService.sendMessage(ActiveMQProducerService.java:24) ~[main/:na]
        at com.xxx.yyy.scada.pi.service.dataService.lambda$sendToActiveMQ$0(MainService.java:58) [main/:na]
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at com.xxx.yyy.scada.pi.service.dataService.sendToActiveMQ(MainService.java:57) [main/:na]
        at com.xxx.yyy.scada.pi.service.dataService.saveScadaData(MainService.java:107) [main/:na]
        at com.xxx.yyy.scada.pi.service.dataService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7d8d2e93.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.invokeMethod(CglibAopProxy.java:386) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.access$000(CglibAopProxy.java:85) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:704) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at com.xxx.yyy.scada.pi.service.dataService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b3222122.saveScadaData(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at com.xxx.yyy.scada.pi.controller.ScadaController.lambda$dataIngestJsonHandler$0(ScadaController.java:66) ~[main/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:38) ~[activemq-client-5.16.5.jar:5.16.5]
```

So may I know the reason for above error ? And how can I resolve this ?

Comment: I would try PooledConnectionFactory.

Comment: @Mar-Z can you please explain me in detail ?

Comment: Provide more details from the exception and be clear about what component is throwing it, right now it is to vague to comment on.

Comment: @TimBish I have edited my question and added proper stacktrace to it. Let me know if you need some more information.

Comment: You've omitted the chain of the causal exception so still not clear who is the source of the error.